# Como hacer una busqueda exacta en datatables.net

Tags: codeigniter, busqueda

Espero me ayuden en este problema, datatables esta implementado y funciona de maravilla, no tengo quejas, pero a la hora de buscar es que tengo un problema:
en el campo search coloco cualquier letra o numero o palabras y el me busca los registros que contengan esos caracteres, y lo que quiero es que busque que contenga el caracter al inicio del campo..
Ejemplo: quiero buscar los registros que empiecen por el numero 2: 2000 21000 2340
Pero la busqueda la hace asi: wwer2popo 99962892, osea busca los registros que contengan los caracteres sin importar la posicion
Supongo que hace la busqueda asi: busca en las columnas  *2* cuando lo que que quiero es busque asi: 2*.
Me pueden ayudar a configurar ese tipo de busqueda.

PorFavor!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.